# Mapping a list of class object to another list

Tags: java, class, kotlin

I have the following two classes. An `originalPerson` and an `originalAddress`. An `originalPerson` has a list of available addresses named as `location`.

```
class originalPerson (
    val firstName: kotlin.String,
    val LastName: kotlin.String,
    val isAvailable: kotlin.Boolean,
    val location: kotlin.collections.List<originalAddress>
)

class originalAddress (
    val first: String? = null,
    val second: String? = null,
    val third: String? = null,
)
```

I have also two more class which are pretty similar to the classes above but with custom number of fields.

```
class customPerson (
    val firstName: kotlin.String,
    val LastName: kotlin.String,
    val location: kotlin.collections.List<customAddress>
)

class customAddress (
    val first: String? = null,
    val second: String? = null,
)
```

I have a method that returns an `originalPerson` object but I want to map it to `customPerson` object and return that instead. I am not sure how to correctly do that.

I have come as far as mapping `firstName` and `lastName` of `originalPerson` to `customPerson` but I don´t know how to map `List<originalAddress>` to `List<customAddress>`. Here´s my code so far:

```
val result = it.value.flatMap { r -> r.fieldsMap.entries}
                              .map { r -> customPerson(r.firstName, r.LastName, **List<customAddress>**)}
```

I would appreciate some help with the syntax of mapping `List<originalAddress>` to `List<customAddress>`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these need to be unrelated classes?  Your OriginalPerson class (by convention, class names always start with a capital letter) is basically your CustomPerson with a few fields added; so the obvious implementation is for OriginalPerson to be a subclass of CustomPerson; that way you don't have to repeat the fields they share (except possibly in the constructor).  You wouldn't need to do any mapping then; an OriginalPerson _is_ a (particular type of) CustomPerson, so you can use it wherever you're expecting a CustomPerson.

Comment: Similarly, OriginalAddress could be a subclass of CustomAddress.  (Handling the list of addresses neatly would be slightly more tricky, and might need a type parameter on the CustomPerson class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right you're almost there, just need another map:

```
val result = it.value.flatMap { r -> r.fieldsMap.entries}
     .map { r -> customPerson(
                   r.firstName, 
                   r.LastName, 
                   r.location.map { customAddress(it.first, it.second) }
                 )
     }
```

I just use `map` like you did in the first place and create a list of custom addresses.

You can, if you want, create a method for this:

```
private fun toCustomAddresses(originalPerson: originalPerson) =
  originalPerson.location.map { customAddress(it.first, it.second) }
```

And use it like:

```
val result = it.value.flatMap { r -> r.fieldsMap.entries}
     .map { r -> customPerson(
                   r.firstName, 
                   r.LastName, 
                   toCustomAddresses(r)
                 )
     }
```

Or even as an extension function:

```
private fun List<originalAddress>.toCustomAddresses() =
  map { customAddress(it.first, it.second) }

val result = it.value.flatMap { r -> r.fieldsMap.entries}
     .map { r -> customPerson(
                   r.firstName, 
                   r.LastName, 
                   r.location.toCustomAddresses()
                 )
     }
```

Personally I prefer this approach, but I think it depends on you and your own guidelines.